# How do I reference a JAXB POJO in a mule flow

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, mule

I have successfully unmarshalled an `XML` document into a `JAXB` object but now, I would like to reference the object in the flow and insert the value of it's properties into a database table.

The flow is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd">
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="10009" basePath="/ipay/bra" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<mulexml:jaxb-context name="JAXB_Context" packageNames="com.dhg.api" doc:name="JAXB Context"/>
<flow name="transaction_initiation_testFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/transaction" doc:name="HTTP">
        <http:response-builder>
            <http:header headerName="Content-Type" value="text/xml"/>
        </http:response-builder>
    </http:listener>
    <mulexml:jaxb-xml-to-object-transformer returnClass="com.dhg.api.PAYMENTS" jaxbContext-ref="JAXB_Context" doc:name="XML to JAXB Object"/>
    <logger message="#[payload.transaction.email]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
</flow>
</mule>
```

The object is as follows:

```
package com.dhg.api;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;



@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {"transaction"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "PAYMENTS")
public class PAYMENTS {

@XmlElement(name = "TRANSACTION", required = true)
protected PAYMENTS.TRANSACTION transaction;

public PAYMENTS.TRANSACTION getTRANSACTION() {
    return transaction;
}

public void setTRANSACTION(PAYMENTS.TRANSACTION value) {
    this.transaction = value;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "entity",
    "useraddress1",
    "useraddress2",
    "useraddress3",
    "usercountry",
    "userparish",
    "totalamount",
    "payer",
    "status",
    "ipaynumber",
    "email"
})
public static class TRANSACTION {

    @XmlElement(name = "ENTITY", required = true)
    protected PAYMENTS.TRANSACTION.ENTITY entity;
    @XmlElement(name = "USERADDRESS1", required = true)
    protected String useraddress1;
    @XmlElement(name = "USERADDRESS2", required = true)
    protected String useraddress2;
    @XmlElement(name = "USERADDRESS3", required = true)
    protected String useraddress3;
    @XmlElement(name = "USERCOUNTRY", required = true)
    protected String usercountry;
    @XmlElement(name = "USERPARISH", required = true)
    protected String userparish;
    @XmlElement(name = "TOTALAMOUNT")
    protected float totalamount;
    @XmlElement(name = "PAYER", required = true)
    protected String payer;
    @XmlElement(name = "STATUS", required = true)
    protected String status;
    @XmlElement(name = "IPAYNUMBER")
    protected int ipaynumber;
    @XmlElement(name = "EMAIL", required = true)
    protected String email;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "txdate")
    protected String txdate;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "txno")
    protected String txno;

    public PAYMENTS.TRANSACTION.ENTITY getENTITY() {
        return entity;
    }

    public void setENTITY(PAYMENTS.TRANSACTION.ENTITY value) {
        this.entity = value;
    }

    public String getUSERADDRESS1() {
        return useraddress1;
    }
    public void setUSERADDRESS1(String value) {
        this.useraddress1 = value;
    }

    public String getUSERADDRESS2() {
        return useraddress2;
    }

    public void setUSERADDRESS2(String value) {
        this.useraddress2 = value;
    }

    public String getUSERADDRESS3() {
        return useraddress3;
    }

    public void setUSERADDRESS3(String value) {
        this.useraddress3 = value;
    }

    public String getUSERCOUNTRY() {
        return usercountry;
    }

    public void setUSERCOUNTRY(String value) {
        this.usercountry = value;
    }

    public String getUSERPARISH() {
        return userparish;
    }

    public void setUSERPARISH(String value) {
        this.userparish = value;
    }

    public float getTOTALAMOUNT() {
        return totalamount;
    }

    public void setTOTALAMOUNT(float value) {
        this.totalamount = value;
    }

    public String getPAYER() {
        return payer;
    }

    public void setPAYER(String value) {
        this.payer = value;
    }

    public String getSTATUS() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setSTATUS(String value) {
        this.status = value;
    }

    public int getIPAYNUMBER() {
        return ipaynumber;
    }

    public void setIPAYNUMBER(int value) {
        this.ipaynumber = value;
    }

    public String getEMAIL() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEMAIL(String value) {
        this.email = value;
    }

    public String getTxdate() {
        return txdate;
    }

    public void setTxdate(String value) {
        this.txdate = value;
    }

    public String getTxno() {
        return txno;
    }

    public void setTxno(String value) {
        this.txno = value;
    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "account"
    })
    public static class ENTITY {

        @XmlElement(name = "ACCOUNT", required = true)
        protected PAYMENTS.TRANSACTION.ENTITY.ACCOUNT account;
        @XmlAttribute(name = "biller")
        protected String biller;

        public PAYMENTS.TRANSACTION.ENTITY.ACCOUNT getACCOUNT() {
            return account;
        }
        public void setACCOUNT(PAYMENTS.TRANSACTION.ENTITY.ACCOUNT value) {
            this.account = value;
        }
        public String getBiller() {
            return biller;
        }

        public void setBiller(String value) {
            this.biller = value;
        }

        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
            "details"
        })
        public static class ACCOUNT {

            @XmlElement(name = "DETAILS", required = true)
            protected PAYMENTS.TRANSACTION.ENTITY.ACCOUNT.DETAILS details;
            @XmlAttribute(name = "bpnumber")
            protected Integer bpnumber;

            public PAYMENTS.TRANSACTION.ENTITY.ACCOUNT.DETAILS getDETAILS(){
                return details;
            }

            public void setDETAILS(PAYMENTS.TRANSACTION.ENTITY.ACCOUNT.DETAILS value) {
                this.details = value;
            }


            public Integer getBpnumber() {
                return bpnumber;
            }


            public void setBpnumber(Integer value) {
                this.bpnumber = value;
            }


            @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
            @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
                "dockey"
            })
            public static class DETAILS {

                @XmlElement(name = "DOCKEY")
                protected List<PAYMENTS.TRANSACTION.ENTITY.ACCOUNT.DETAILS.DOCKEY> dockey;

                public List<PAYMENTS.TRANSACTION.ENTITY.ACCOUNT.DETAILS.DOCKEY> getDOCKEY() {
                    if (dockey == null) {
                        dockey = new ArrayList<PAYMENTS.TRANSACTION.ENTITY.ACCOUNT.DETAILS.DOCKEY>();
                    }
                    return this.dockey;
                }


                @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
                @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
                    "value"
                })
                public static class DOCKEY {

                    @XmlValue
                    protected String value;
                    @XmlAttribute(name = "payment")
                    protected Float payment;

                    public String getValue() {
                        return value;
                    }

                    public void setValue(String value) {
                        this.value = value;
                    }

                    public Float getPayment() {
                        return payment;
                    }

                    public void setPayment(Float value) {
                        this.payment = value;
                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

}

}
```

After unmarshalling, the object is instantiated as `com.dhg.api.PAYMENTS@some_random_string`, which makes it difficult to reference. So my question is simply, how can I refer to this object and be able to access the values for use elsewhere in the flow.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you get from `<logger message="#[payload.transaction.email]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>`?

Comment: It throws an exception - java.lang.NullPointerException. However, when the unmarshalling is done, the payload is not null and has an object named com.dhg.api.PAYMENTS@3d604fa5. I can browse the payload in the debugger and see all of the values in the object..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setter/getter is not compliant with property names in :

```
public PAYMENTS.TRANSACTION getTRANSACTION() {
    return transaction;
}

public void setTRANSACTION(PAYMENTS.TRANSACTION value) {
    this.transaction = value;
}
```

So in `<logger message="#[payload.transaction.email]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>` the `transaction` part is null.

The correct getter name is `getTransaction` and is the same for setter. Change them please

Comment: Thank you so much. I am not sure why I had not seen that, Needless to say, it worked. Thanks.